# Unity: How to create a selection box around gameObjects (Text or images) similar to those in Unity editor?

Tags: unity

In my Unity app, the user has the option to input text and import images. I have implemented these using TMP_Input Field and Image/Sprites respectively. The app also requires that the user knows the currently selected text/image and can also drag these text and images and sometimes resize them.

To achieve this what I need is a UI like this.

[image]

This is the actual Unity editor. But I want to have similar box around my text and images in my app. So that the user knows the current selection and may also drag the text/Image or resize it using the blue circles in the corners.

I am not sure how I can achieve this. One way which I see is to have views which wrap my text and images and these views will have these boxes as the backgrounds.

But I thought that there may be an easier way to do this, probably something that comes with Unity since this looks like a general requirement to me. I am not sure though. What would be the best way to achieve this? WIll I have to do everything from scratch or are there any existing UI components or assets which can make this easier? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just draw these elements manually around the currently selected object? Also this is definitely not a general requirement. It sounds like you are trying to make a program to create other programs (games?) or something similar, which is definitely not what the majority is using Unity for.

Comment: Have you tried using the [outline component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Outline.html)? If so, what was the result? Could you also provide a screenshot of the object hierarchy for an example object you want to outline?

Comment: @TomTsagk Thanks for the input, yeah as I said, that is what I will have to do.

Comment: @disc_code22 Haven't tried it. I can add the screenshot later.